# Button on CollectionView Cell Only Receives Taps After Long Press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I am programmatically adding a UIButton to a custom UICollectionViewCell. Taps on the button are only detected if I do a long press on the cell first. Then the button works as expected. I have to do the same long press on each cell individually in order to get their respective button to recognize taps.

Note that single taps (i.e. didSelectItemAtIndexPath) on cells work as expected. So does long press on a cell. It might be worth noting that UILongPressGestureRecognizer is the only gesture added to the collectionView.

UICollectionViewCell class

```
- (UIButton *)stackInfoButton
{
    if(_stackInfoButton == nil)
    {
        self.stackInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
        [self.stackInfoButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    }
    return _stackInfoButton;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  // Other stuff here. Removed for readability
    self.stackInfoFrame = CGRectMake(4.0f, self.bounds.size.height - self.stackInfoButton.bounds.size.height - 4, self.stackInfoButton.bounds.size.width, self.stackInfoButton.bounds.size.height);
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  // Other stuff here. Removed for readability
  self.stackInfoButton.frame = self.stackInfoFrame;
  [[self contentView] addSubview:self.stackInfoButton];
}
```

UICollectionViewController class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Other stuff here. removed for readability

  self.longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
  self.longPressGesture.delegate = self;
  [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:self.longPressGesture];
  self.longPressGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  DVCardViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kDVCollectionViewCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.indexPath = indexPath;
  // Other stuff here. Removed for readability
  [cell.stackInfoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stackInfoButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     
  return cell;
}

- (void)stackInfoButtonTapped:(id)sender
 {
   NSLog(@">>> Entering %s <<<", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
 }

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    NSLog (@"Touch View : %@", touch.view);
// tried both.
//    DVCardViewCell *cell;
//    if (touch.view == cell.stackInfoButton)
        if ( [touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] )
{
    NSLog(@"Gesture on button, returns no");
    return NO;
}
NSLog(@"Gesture returns outside, yes");
return YES;
}
```

Suggestions appreciated. I've been through many UICollectionView threads on SO. Yet to find one that addresses my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have added a gesture to the collection view, so you need to teach that gesture not to steal touches that it shouldn't get involved with. Add your controller as the delegate of the gesture and implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`. In that method check the view that the touch hit and, if it's a button, return `NO` to prevent the gesture from getting involved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The delegate is set on the gesture. I added shouldReceiveTouch. Results are the same. Please let me know if I misunderstood your suggestion, or you have another idea. Updates above.

Comment: The method is called, and it returns `NO` when you tap the button?

Comment: shouldReceiveTouch is called. I'm not sure how to log what it's returning directly, but if I put a log statement in the if test, it doesn't get logged.

Comment: Put a breakpoint, check what `touch.view` is when you tap the button.

Comment: I put a log statement into `shouldReceiveTouch`. On first tap, or longTouch it says it's returning a view `Touch View : <UIView: 0x7b69abf0; frame = (0 0; 220 132); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b69b010>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b69ae80>>`. After a longTouch, if I tap the button, it tells me a button `<UIButton: 0x7abe1590; frame = (4 106; 22 22); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7abe16b0>` and the shouldReceiveTouch if statement log returns `NO`

Comment: What is the code in `longPress:` doing? That log indicates you have a view in front of the button...

Comment: longPress: is quite a long method. In summary, it behaves similar to iOS springboard. Cell becomes active for dragging and reordering among the other cells. Is there something there I should be looking for? Thanks for hanging with this...

Comment: The key question is why the first tap on the button hits a view. If that didn't happen then you can make the gesture ignore interaction with the button...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.LongPressGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

**Sorry was mistaken. never mind.**

This looks really weird:

```
- (UIButton *)stackInfoButton
{
   if(_stackInfoButton == nil)
   {
      self.stackInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark]; // theoretically your app should crash now
      [self.stackInfoButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
   }
   return _stackInfoButton;
 }
```

Look at `self.stackInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];`

It must be

```
 _stackInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
 [_stackInfoButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

maybe it helps.

Comment: I tried this just before I saw your post. Added to above code, but didn't seem to make a difference. Thanks for the thought...